# "Purpose of Travel" document for Canadian visa

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, proof-of-onward-travel

I am applying for a Canadian Visitor's Visa online and am planning to meet my relatives in Canada. In the "Upload Documents" section of the online application, [they are asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8gZR.jpg) for the following documents:

> Document: Purpose of Travel - Other. You must submit proof that you
> are coming to Canada for a temporary visit
>
> Examples of what you can provide as proof:
>
> A scanned copy of:
>
> - Your flight ticket departing Canada,
> - Your travel itinerary (e.g. places you will visit or stay, such as hotel booking),
> - Proof of a medical appointment

I am unsure of when I will go to Canada, as it is unplanned. Is it necessary for me to show my flight tickets or itinerary to prove that I am going to Canada, or can I show something else to prove this?

Comment: The page you are showing is asking for proof that you LEAVE Canada.

Comment: You most likely do need to tell them when you're going, so as to issue you a visa that covers your stay

Comment: Any suggestions other than flight ticket or itinerary?

Comment: Some countries usually ask for proof of ties in your home country, like a job, family etc. they want to know you're leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched a lot and found out that I can also show wedding invitation, notification of death, funeral notice etc, in Purpose of Travel. One of my friends just created a word document and put "Visiting friends and family" in very big and bold font. The title of the document was "Purpose of travel".

Comment: Hi @maven25, can you share your experience? Did you buy travel itinerary?

Comment: @Vinayak I showed my cousin's wedding card as purpose of travel. One of my other friends created word file and typed travel and sightseeing as purpose of travel. Basically you have to tell them why you are visiting the country.

Comment: Thanks. I applied by typing a word document with purpose of travel is family reunion and sightseeing. I applied from Canada online (for my parents) Do they need to send passport to Canada or Canadian embassy in India.

Comment: @vinayak I am not sure but I guess yes they do need to send their passport with other required docs to the Canadian embassy...you need to check online what all documents are required and whether passport is required.