# Canada visitor visa purpose of travel, bookings and itinerary

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, bookings

When you click purpose of travel section in Canada visitor visa application they say you can show:

Your hotel reservations.
Flight ticket.

Yet Canada immigration advises applicants not to do any bookings or reservations before they receive their visa so, I don't understand how to deal with this section

Comment: You might be misreading the application form. Take a look at this [Travel.SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49162/purpose-of-travel-document-for-canadian-visa?rq=1). Adding a screenshot of what you see on the application form (using the "Edit" button below your question text, followed by pushing the "moon and mountains" button that appears over the text entry box) would be helpful as well.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica the question is almost the same but it hasn't fit what I'm asking about (bookings and reservations)

Answer (score 1):

The [supporting documentation for the visa application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/supporting-documents.html) makes it clear that the itinerary and associated documents are optional.

You should submit any documents on this topic you already have. For some, it makes no sense to not provide them: for instance, if you are going for a conference, giving details of the conference is definitely something you should do. If you intend to stay with someone, you should provide the relevant details.

If for whatever reason you have already made reservations, include the details. Otherwise, giving the broad lines of your itinerary, both how you get to/from Canada and what you will be doing there is a good idea: it shows that you have researched the topic, and allows you and the immigration officer to make an estimate of the associated cost to see if that matches other answers and documents and your financial situation.

The more a accurate and consistent the picture you paint the better.